# Find the transfer function H(s) assuming a signal input i,in(t) and signal output, i,out(t)

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function, laplace-transform

I am having trouble answering this question for my Signals and Systems class and would appreciate any assistance.

***Find the transfer function, \$H(s)\$, assuming a signal input \$i_{in}(t)\$ and signal output, \$i_{out}(t)\$.***

My initial plan is to find the equivalent resistance of resistors R1, R2, and R3, and R4, R5, and RL, then place the circuit in the time domain, i.e. L1 → sL, v(t) → V(s).

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

[image]

I'd appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction or point out any flaws in my plan.

Edit: hfe = 50

Comment: Did your instructor give you some requirements? For example, are you meant to produce the transfer function in pure symbolic form before substituting the components values. If you are allowed to use the actual values during the derivation process, you can simplify the calculations (giving up some understanding of the process and some error-checking, though).

Comment: My instructor did not specify, I imagine either method is fine. I had planned on deriving the transfer function and then substituting in the component values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving this kind of problems in a smart way usually requires knowing your basic theorems and circuit theory formulas well.

Thévenin's/Norton's theorem (and the consequent source transformations formulas), voltage divider formulas, current divider formulas are your friends here.

Your goal is to determine
$$
H(s) = \frac {I_{out}} {I_{in}} 
$$

So you should start by transforming the circuit's components in the s-domain, which is fairly easy since the circuit is made up mostly of resistors, which remain the same in the transformation.

Then you should try to express \$I_{out}(s)\$ in terms of \$I_{in}(s)\$. This is not particularly difficult because there is no feedback path, so essentially you could go from input to output expressing some intermediate variable (voltage or current) in terms of another with simple applications of the above formulas.

For example, here is a possible line of action (not the only one).

R1 can be eliminated (you can replace it with a short circuit) because it is in series with a current source, so it can't influence the output in any way.

Once you get rid of \$R1\$, \$I_b(s)\$ can be expressed in terms of \$I_{in}\$ just with the current divider formula. BTW, if you are allowed to use the component values during the derivation process, you can immediately see that \$I_b\$ is half \$I_{in}\$, since \$R2\$ and \$R3\$ are equal.

So you now know how \$h_{fe}I_b\$ is related to \$I_{in}\$. At this point you can relate \$I_{out}\$ with \$h_{fe}I_b\$ with just one formula since \$h_{fe}I_b\$ feeds a 3-branch current divider whose branches are \$R4\$, \$R5\$ and \$L1\$ in series with \$RL\$.

The only difficulty here is that you must apply the formula using admittances instead of usual DC conductances. So you need to calculate the admittance of the output branch (\$L1\$ in series with \$RL\$).

---

**EDIT** (to address a request of clarification in a comment).

As you know the impedance of a linear bipole in s-domain is indicated with \$Z(s)\$, and its real and imaginary parts are the resistance \$R(s)\$ and the reactance \$X(s)\$.

$$
Z(s) = R(s) + j X(s)
$$

Some formulas are easier to write if you introduce another complex quantity, called **admittance** and indicated with \$Y(s)\$, which is defined as the reciprocal of the impedance:

$$
Y(s) = \frac 1 { Z(s) }
$$

For completeness it's worth nothing that the real and imaginary parts of \$Y\$ are called **conductance** \$G(s)\$ and **susceptance** \$B(s)\$, respectively.

$$
Y(s) = G(s) + j B(s)
$$

The 3-branches current divider (3-branches in parallel) formula that I mentioned can be written in general like this:

$$
I_n(s) 
= I_{tot}(s) \cdot \frac{ Y_n(s) } { Y_1(s) + Y_2(s) + Y_3(s) }
$$

Where \$I_n\$ is the current in the n-th branch, \$I_{tot}\$ is the current feeding the divider (total current) and \$Y_k\$ is the admittance of the k-th branch (\$k=1,2,3\$).

This can be easily generalized for an arbitrary number N of branches by just putting in the denominator the sum of all the branch admittances. This formula can be easily proven using Kirchhoff's laws and the s-domain Ohm's law: \$ V(s) = Z(s) \cdot I(s) \$.

Comment: So to clarify, you're saying I should find out what Iin(s) will be after it is affected by R2 and R3 using current division, then find what that current will be after it is affected by the hfe, R4, R5, and RL.

Comment: @JordanStanley That's an approach. Of course you should know about current dividers and how to apply the relevant formulas. It doesn't really matter the approach you take, the end result will be the same.

Comment: Hello again, would using current division to find the current across RL allow me to find Iout(s)?

Comment: @JordanStanley Yes, the current *through* (not "across") the branch comprised of L1 and RL *is* Iout. And Iout is a fraction of hfeIb that you can calculate using the "multiple branches" current division formula (among other methods). This formula requires that you compute the admittance of all 3 branches into which hfeIb splits.

Comment: Okay I believe I understand. So, when I use current division should I use 1/R instead of simply R because I need to use admittance.

Also, I am correct in my understanding that the admittance of resistance, is 1/R?

Comment: @JordanStanley Yes, the admittance is the reciprocal of impedance. So if the impedance is R, the corresponding admittance is 1/R. Of course the output branch has an L in it, so its impedance is in the form R+sL and its admittance is in the form 1/(R+sL).

Answer (score 2):

I think, there is a straight forward solution to the problem:

- Find Ib as a function of Iin (simple task), and
- find Vout (or Iout) as a function of hfe*Ib using Kirchhoffs and Ohms laws.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG2wpl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
0&=\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4+\text{I}_9\\
\\
\text{I}_9&=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_{10}&=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_8&=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_{10}\\
\\
0&=\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_3+\text{I}_7+\text{I}_8\\
\\
\text{I}_7&=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_1
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [KVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_voltage_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5&=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_6&=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\text{I}_6&=\frac{\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_7}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}&=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
0&=\text{n}\cdot\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}+\text{I}_9\\
\\
\text{I}_9&=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}+\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\text{I}_{10}&=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}+\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\text{I}_8&=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}+\text{I}_{10}\\
\\
0&=\text{n}\cdot\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}+\text{I}_7+\text{I}_8\\
\\
\text{I}_7&=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}&=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_9&=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}+\frac{\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_7}\\
\\
\text{I}_{10}&=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}+\frac{\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_7}\\
\\
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can solve for the transfer function:

$$\mathcal{H}:=\frac{\text{I}_6}{\text{I}_1}=-\frac{\text{n}\text{R}_2\text{R}_4\text{R}_5}{\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\left(\text{R}_5\left(\text{R}_6+\text{R}_7\right)+\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6+\text{R}_7\right)\right)}\tag4$$

Where I used the following mathematica code to solve for all the voltages and currents:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I3, 0 == n*I3 + I4 + I9, I9 == I5 + I6, 
   I10 == I5 + I6, I8 == I4 + I10, 0 == n*I3 + I7 + I8, I7 == I0 + I3,
    I2 == I0 + I1, I1 == (V1 - V2)/R1, I2 == V2/R2, I3 == V2/R3, 
   I4 == V3/R4, I5 == V3/R5, I6 == (V3 - V4)/R6, I6 == V4/R7}, {I0, 
   I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, I8, I9, I10, V1, V2, V3, V4}]]

Out[1]={{I0 -> -((I1 R2)/(R2 + R3)), I2 -> (I1 R3)/(R2 + R3), 
  I3 -> (I1 R2)/(R2 + R3), 
  I4 -> -((I1 n R2 R5 (R6 + R7))/((R2 + R3) (R5 (R6 + R7) + 
       R4 (R5 + R6 + R7)))), 
  I5 -> -((I1 n R2 R4 (R6 + R7))/((R2 + R3) (R5 (R6 + R7) + 
       R4 (R5 + R6 + R7)))), 
  I6 -> -((I1 n R2 R4 R5)/((R2 + R3) (R5 (R6 + R7) + 
       R4 (R5 + R6 + R7)))), I7 -> 0, I8 -> -((I1 n R2)/(R2 + R3)), 
  I9 -> -((I1 n R2 R4 (R5 + R6 + R7))/((R2 + R3) (R5 (R6 + R7) + 
       R4 (R5 + R6 + R7)))), 
  I10 -> -((
    I1 n R2 R4 (R5 + R6 + R7))/((R2 + R3) (R5 (R6 + R7) + 
       R4 (R5 + R6 + R7)))), V1 -> I1 (R1 + (R2 R3)/(R2 + R3)), 
  V2 -> (I1 R2 R3)/(R2 + R3), 
  V3 -> -((I1 n R2 R4 R5 (R6 + R7))/((R2 + R3) (R5 (R6 + R7) + 
       R4 (R5 + R6 + R7)))), 
  V4 -> -((I1 n R2 R4 R5 R7)/((R2 + R3) (R5 (R6 + R7) + 
       R4 (R5 + R6 + R7))))}}
```

---

Now, applying this to your circuit we need to use (from now on I use the lowercase letters for the function in the 'complex' s-domain where I used [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)):

$$\text{R}_6=\text{sL}\tag5$$

So, the transfer function will be:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)=-\frac{\text{n}\text{R}_2\text{R}_4\text{R}_5}{\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\left(\text{R}_5\left(\text{sL}+\text{R}_7\right)+\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_5+\text{sL}+\text{R}_7\right)\right)}\tag6$$

Now, simplifying by using \$\text{R}_\text{a}:=\text{R}_1=\text{R}_2=\text{R}_3\$, \$\text{R}_\text{b}:=\text{R}_5=\text{R}_7\$ and \$\text{R}_4=10\text{R}_\text{b}\$ gives:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)&=-\frac{\text{n}\text{R}_\text{a}\cdot10\text{R}_\text{b}\cdot\text{R}_\text{b}}{\left(\text{R}_\text{a}+\text{R}_\text{a}\right)\left(\text{R}_\text{b}\left(\text{sL}+\text{R}_\text{b}\right)+10\text{R}_\text{b}\left(\text{R}_\text{b}+\text{sL}+\text{R}_\text{b}\right)\right)}\\
\\
&=-\frac{5\text{nR}_\text{b}}{21\text{R}_\text{b}+11\text{Ls}}
\end{split}\tag7
\end{equation}

So, when we use the transformation \$\text{s}=\text{j}\omega\$ (where \$\text{j}^2=-1\$), we get:

$$\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=-\frac{5\text{nR}_\text{b}}{21\text{R}_\text{b}+11\text{L}\omega\text{j}}\tag8$$

The magnitude response can be found by solving for the absolute value of equation \$(8)\$:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|&=\left|-\frac{5\text{nR}_\text{b}}{21\text{R}_\text{b}+11\text{L}\omega\text{j}}\right|\\
\\
&=\left|-1\right|\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\left|5\text{nR}_\text{b}\right|}{\displaystyle\left|21\text{R}_\text{b}+11\text{L}\omega\text{j}\right|}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle5\text{nR}_\text{b}}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(21\text{R}_\text{b}\right)^2+\left(11\text{L}\omega\right)^2}}
\end{split}\tag9
\end{equation}

And the argument is given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\arg\left(\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)&=\arg\left(-\frac{5\text{nR}_\text{b}}{21\text{R}_\text{b}+11\text{L}\omega\text{j}}\right)\\
\\
&=\arg\left(-1\right)+\arg\left(5\text{nR}_\text{b}\right)-\arg\left(21\text{R}_\text{b}+11\text{L}\omega\text{j}\right)\\
\\
&=\pi+0-\arctan\left(\frac{11\text{L}\omega}{21\text{R}_\text{b}}\right)\\
\\
&=\pi-\arctan\left(\frac{11\text{L}\omega}{21\text{R}_\text{b}}\right)
\end{split}\tag{10}
\end{equation}

Applying this with your values, we get:

- $$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)=-\frac{50\text{n}}{210+11\text{s}}\tag{11}$$
- $$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\displaystyle50\text{n}}{\displaystyle\sqrt{44100+\left(11\omega\right)^2}}\tag{12}$$
- $$\arg\left(\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)=\pi-\arctan\left(\frac{11\omega}{210}\right)\tag{13}$$

Comment: The OP's is a homework question. Our current policy for this kind of questions is not to provide complete solutions, but to give only outlines of possible solutions or hints. Moreover, the OP was tasked to *solve* the circuit. It is highly unlikely that they are allowed to use symbolic algebra programs to do the gruntwork. These kind of exercises are usually given to students to see how they tackle a difficult problem using smart approaches, not to see if they can write a 8+ equations system and solve it using a PC. The important thing for a student is the process, not the actual solution.

Comment: Yes, I also believe that it does not help the questioner much to have the solution presented here as the result of a computer calculation.